# Debug 'message sent to deallocated instance'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

OK, so here I am again facing the dreaded `message sent to deallocated instance`...

- I'm using [DMTabBar](https://github.com/malcommac/DMTabBar) (basically an Xcode-like TabBar control)
- ARC is enabled

**Now, here's the deal :**

- The example accompanying the control works fine
- I've enabled Zombies (and even trying debugging using Instruments, though - to be honest - I don't know what to be looking for)
- The `deallocated` instance is the `tabBarItems` array of the TabBar (the one hosting the different buttons).

**This is how I add the items :**

```
NSMutableArray* sidebarItems = [@[
        [DMTabBarItem tabBarItemWithIcon:[NSImage templateImageNamed:@"One" withSize:iconSize] tag:0 tooltip:@"Files"],
        [DMTabBarItem tabBarItemWithIcon:[NSImage templateImageNamed:@"Two" withSize:iconSize] tag:1 tooltip:@"Explorer"],
        [DMTabBarItem tabBarItemWithIcon:[NSImage templateImageNamed:@"Three" withSize:iconSize] tag:2 tooltip:@"Bookmarks"],
        [DMTabBarItem tabBarItemWithIcon:[NSImage templateImageNamed:@"Four" withSize:iconSize] tag:3 tooltip:@"Search"]
    ] mutableCopy];

[sidebarTabs setTabBarItems:items];

// Handle selection events
[sidebarTabs handleTabBarItemSelection:^(DMTabBarItemSelectionType selectionType, DMTabBarItem *targetTabBarItem, NSUInteger targetTabBarItemIndex) {
        if (selectionType == DMTabBarItemSelectionType_WillSelect) {
            [sidebarTabView selectTabViewItem:[sidebarTabView.tabViewItems objectAtIndex:targetTabBarItemIndex]];
        } else if (selectionType == DMTabBarItemSelectionType_DidSelect) {
        }
    }];
```

**This is how the different elements are declared :**

```
@interface myAppl : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet DMTabBar* sidebarTabs;
    IBOutlet NSTabView* sidebarTabView;
}
```

**And this is `DMTabBar`'s interface (the most "important" part) :**

```
@interface DMTabBar : NSView {

}

// set an NSArray of DMTabBarItem elements to populate the DMTabBar
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray*           tabBarItems;

// change selected item by passing a DMTabBarItem object (ignored if selectedTabBarItem is not contained inside tabBarItems)
@property (nonatomic,assign) DMTabBarItem*      selectedTabBarItem;
```

---

Could you please explain to me what it is that I'm doing wrong? I'm definitely *not* a guru with Memory Management (yep, I admit I have some studying to do) but I'm definitely gonna kill myself over this one...

I'm setting the `tabBarItems` and they seem to be there (at least at first). Why are they being released? *(remember both the control and project code use ARC).*

Any ideas? (Please let me know in case you need to know anything else...)

Comment: Ewwwww, iVar IBOutlets!  What is this, ObjC 1.0?

Comment: @CodaFi Initially they were declared as properties, but I'm so desperate that I keep trying every single possible combination...

Comment: Is it possible that you might have a threading problem?  UIKit and threads do not agree in the slightest.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks for having a look at the issue. However, I've managed to fix it (and as it usually happens with such issues, there is nothing universally comprehensible I could post regarding the solution). Btw, the post (as tagged) is *not* about Cocoa Touch and UIKit, but OSX-related.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running with the usual memory debugging techniques, i.e.

- **Instruments** with Zombies, and
- setting the various flags in Xcode's **Edit Scheme > Diagnostics > Memory Management** tab?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure how Instruments should be used, 2) As mentioned, I've already identified which specific object is being released. So?

Answer (score 0):

Only use assign when it's not an object, delegate, and IBoutlet.

change this:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) DMTabBarItem*      selectedTabBarItem;
```

to this:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) DMTabBarItem*      selectedTabBarItem;
```